# How to configure MongoTemplate on Spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I will work with some old projects developed with Spring, I usually work with spring boot so I started doing some tests to practice before starting, I looked for some configuration examples but i just found few examples (there are many info for spring boot but not for spring) and non of them worked for me. Could anyone show me the easiest way to use mongoTemplate with spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring-boot class :

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApp {...}

Mongo repo :

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {}

dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>{mongo.driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

also refer to https://mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/